List ALL Automation rule in Azure Sentinel with powershell
I want to list ALL Automation Rules (AR) of an Azure Sentinel workspace using Powershell cmdlet Get-AzSentinelAutomationRule from module Az.SecurityInsights version 3.1.2. For testing purpose I have a Sentinel workspace with two simple AR.
When I doing this on AR with basic condition, it works. Basic conditions are the following for both AR:

But if I add a more complex condition to one AR:

The Powershell cmdlet Get-AzSentinelAutomationRule seems to see only one AR (the one with simple condition). Even if try to get the missing one with his ID, I'm getting an error that the Resource does not exist.

It might be a very transient issue related to the module updates or resource names are not given properly.
Need to check below:

Make sure that you have updated the security insights module to the latest version releases with Update-module command.

Check that the rule with added conditions has been successfully created in the portal under the selected workspace as there is chance of mismatching workspace names.

Clear the cache in the console using az cache purge command and try executing the command again.

Also verify that you are providing the correct syntax along with the  Get-AzSentinelAutomationRule command.


I have created two rules under a sentinel workspace, one with the basic conditions and the other with the complex conditions as shown below.

Once it is done, I have executed the below command and was able to get the expected output.
$ARs = Get-AzSentinelAutomationRule -ResourceGroupName "xxx" -workspaceName "newws"
$ARs.name

Output:



I will try all your recommendations, i have successfully list all AR with invoke-method on the API endpoint with version 2024-06-01-preview.

Could it be related to the location of my workspace ? Did you try to add an or condition, for me it works with and but not when there is an or
